# Predicting product's category by search term

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, neural-network

**Problem:** User performs product's search using search term, we should define most related category(categories is descending order) to that search term.

**Given:** Products set, around 50000(Could be ten times more) products. Products contains title, description, and list of categories it belongs to.

**Model:**

**Pre-processing** Perform stemming and remove stopwords from product's title and description. Put all unique stemmed words in WORDS list of size N. Put all categories to CATEGORIES list of size M.

**Fitting** Use neural network which has N input neurons and M outputs.

**Training** For product which has words w1, w3, w4, w6 input will be x=[1 0 1 1 0 1 ...] in which elements which index corresponds to thouse words index in WORDS will be set to 1. If product belongs to categories c1, c3, c25 it corresponds to y =[1 0 1 ... 1(25-th position)...] Predicting step. As input put user search term stemmed tokens that should as output give us prediction of most related category.

Is this model correct way for solving such a problem? What are the recommendation for hidden NN layers configuration. Any advice will be helpful, I'm completely new to Machine Learning.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's the correct way of solving the problem, since you're dealing with a multi-label classification problem. That is, a sample can belong to several classes simultaneously, or to a single class, or to none of the classes (categories).

This is a good example on Python: [multi-label classification](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_multilabel.html).
You can get more details [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/classification-with-more-than-two-classes-1.html).

As for hidden layers configuration, the first approach is to use cross-validation to test the accuracy on the test set. But if you want to go further, please read [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw).